# Expresión regular que no coincide desde el inicio en otro intento

Tags: javascript, regex

Pruebo la expresión con 2 casos diferentes en que **ambos debería devolver `true`**, ¿por qué entonces **solo en 1 caso termina devolviéndome** `true`?

```js
var palabras = [
  
  "profesor",
  "profesores",
  "Objeto",
  "Automovil"
];
var ex6 = /^(a|p)/gi;

console.log(palabras[0] + ": " + ex6.test(palabras[0])); // Acepta profesor
console.log(palabras[3] + ": " + ex6.test(palabras[3])); // Acepta Automovil
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Estás utilizando el modificador `/g`, por lo que al intentar la misma expresión sobre otro texto, toma como inicio la posición en la que terminó la coincidencia anterior.

> Es decir que, luego de coincidir con la primera letra de:
>
> ```
> profesor
> ^
> Coincide con /^(a|p)/gi
> ```
>
> La posición para realizar el segundo intento es 1 (desde la segunda
>   letra), y al compararlo con el otro texto:
>
> ```
> A|utomovil
>  |
>  |> No coincide con /^(a|p)/gi desde acá
> ```
>
> Jamás podría coincidir.

Para solucionarlo, podrías:

- **No usar el modificador `/g`** (que no tiene sentido usarlo en este caso porque con `^` sólo puede haber 1 coincidencia y no varias).

  ```js
  var palabras = [
          "profesor",
          "profesores",
          "Objeto",
          "Automovil"
      ],
      ex6 = /^(a|p)/i;

  console.log(palabras[0] + ": " + ex6.test(palabras[0]));
  console.log(palabras[3] + ": " + ex6.test(palabras[3]));
  ```
- O **reiniciar la posición** en la que inicia la coincidencia.

  ```js
  var palabras = [
          "profesor",
          "profesores",
          "Objeto",
          "Automovil"
      ],
      ex6 = /^(a|p)/gi;

  console.log(palabras[0] + ": " + ex6.test(palabras[0]));

  //Reiniciamos la posición para que intente desde el inicio del texto
  ex6.lastIndex = 0;
  console.log(palabras[3] + ": " + ex6.test(palabras[3]));
  ```

  El nombre de la propiedad [**RegExp.lastIndex**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/lastIndex) puede parecer mal asignado, porque no es exclusivamente la última (*last*) posición, pero es al fin y al cabo la posición en la que iniciará el próximo intento de coincidencia. Es parte de todos los objetos [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/RegExp), y sólo se establece como `0` al iniciar el objeto, luego de una coincidencia fallida, o manualmente, como en este caso.

---

> Nota: para dos opciones de letras es preferible, y un poco más
>   eficiente, utilizar una clase de caracteres:
>
> ```
> /^[ap]/i
> ```